# Irreducibility, dimension of $2\times 3$ matrices of rank at most 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm very poor at abstract algebra.

Consider $X$, the set of $2\times3$ matricies with rank at most $1$ over a base field.  With each matrix interpreted as a 6-tuple, show $X$ is irreducible and compute its dimension.

My attempt:

Elements of $X$ are of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&ca&da\\b&cb&db\end{bmatrix}$.  We know an affine variety is irreducible if it is an integral domain, but even finding $I(X)$ is stumping me.  Under the Zariski topology, we want those polynomials in 6 variables which vanish on $X$.  My gut goes to $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2+(x_1y_3-x_3y_1)^2$ (top row is $x$ bottom row is $y$) which certainly vanishes on $X$, but is this the generator of $I(X)$?  As far as dimension is concerned, I have no idea how to show maximality of any chain I find.

---

Following KReiser's hint:

Elements of $X$ are not of that form *necessarily*.  Instead write elements of $x$ as $\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\\x_4&x_5&x_6\end{bmatrix}$, where $x_1x_5=x_2x_4$, $x_1x_6=x_3x_4$ and $x_2x_6=x_3x_5$.  These conditions suggest that $I(X)=\langle x_1x_5-x_2x_4,x_1x_6-x_3x_4,x_2x_6-x_3x_5\rangle$.  I'm not sure how to prove this; suppose a polynomial $p$ had $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$.  In particular $p(0,0,0,0,0,0)=0$ and $p(z,0,0,0,0,0)=p(0,z,0,0,0,0)=\cdots=p(0,0,0,0,0,z)=0$ for $z\in\mathbb R$.  Therefore $p$ has no lone terms $x_i^k$.  Is this the right track to achieve $p\in I(X)$ as posed above?

Then to show integral domain: let $a,b\in A(X)$ be nonzero.  Suppose $A(X)$ is not an integral domain, that is, $ab\in I(X)$.  I'm looking for patterns in small elements of $I(X)$, struggling to find a contradiction.

Comment: While the matrices of the form you write down are in $X$, not every matrix in $X$ is of that form: consider something with first column zero, for instance. You also seem to believe that $I(X)$ will be generated by one element ("the generator of $I(X)$") - why? On a positive note, your identification of $x_1y_2-x_2y_1$ and $x_1y_3-x_3y_1$ as elements of $I(X)$ is good, and you should explore that more.

Comment: +1 after I get a few more rep; this is helpful.  Not quite done yet -- once the two above roadblocks are cleared, the dimension should pop right out I think.

Comment: @BurntHardRyeMan You have the right equations now. That they are enough is a fact from linear algebra; do you know how to characterize the rank of a matrix in terms of its minors?

Comment: The rank is the largest nonzero minor, right?